# How to improve cross domain page calling/loading

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cross-domain

> NOTE: I am aware this is a little bit more *Server* than *programming*
>   but StackOverflow is a good place for `.htaccess` information I
>    figured that some of you more
>   Beautiful StackOverflowers would have some useful advise.  Many
>   thanks.

I am on a LAMP stack with multiple domains and a cPanel back end.

I have a domain, `www.domainA.com` which will eventually be one of numerous domains A-E (not literally A-E, but you get the idea), all of these domains call the content for certain pages from another domain, `DomainM.com`, `DomainM.com` is directly accessible via the web but the idea is that this will absolutely not be the primary source of visitors.

The key to this is that someone visits `DomainA.com` and sees content from `www.DomainM.com` *but the URL remains on www.DomainA.com*.

I have currently set this up in the .htaccess on `DomainA.com` (from advice from my server guy at work). I'm pretty sure that .htaccess redirecting is not the best way of doing this but it does work:

.htaccess on `www.DomainA.com` :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(referencepage)/?$ http://www.DomainM.co.uk/$1 [P,NC]
```

this takes the address `www.domainA.org.uk/referencepage` and loads the server data from `www.domainM.co.uk/referencepage` while the visitors does not get to see `DomainM.com`.

So I have two questions:

1) Various measurements show that approximately 30% of the time, this system takes 2-4 seconds longer to load the pages. I *think* this would be due to dealing with two servers and I *think* .htaccess is not the most efficient way of dealing with this declaration. We do not have access to httpd.conf.

**How can I improve the loading speeds of this setup?**

1b) How can I get a more detailed report on what takes the most time to load and display the page? **solved**

2) Is there a significantly more efficient/effective way of setting up this form of layout, the primary objecting being to display `DomainM` on `DomainA` without the visitor "leaving" `DomainA` ?

P.S> If there is a name for what I'm trying to do, I can update the question title and it can be used for reference searching for both others and for myself. Cheers.

## UPDATE

I have simplified my `.htaccess` rules a little, so now they read:

```
#This is to force to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

#Start biz pages
#for each business in turn: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.DomainA.org.uk/businessName$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.Domain.co.uk/$1 [P,NC]
```

So that `www.DomainA.org.uk/business` loads `www.Domain.co.uk/business` (which is infact URL rewritten on Domain.co.uk to be: `www.Domain.co.uk/page.php?name=business`  ).

## UPDATE 2

My Complete htaccess on the `DomainA` site:

```
Options -Indexes

#force www usage.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

#Start business pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.southwold.org.uk/cranbourne$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.blythweb.co.uk/$1 [P,NC]

... (all pages references are the same structure as above) ... 

#End business Pages

#prevent error looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

<Files php.ini>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how Rewrite Engine works. For example, take `http://domainA.com/referencepage`. When you request this page, your browser sends a request to web-server to retrieve it. Your web-server checks for `.htaccess` and reads its rewrite rules.

Your rewrite condition says (I changed them to match `domainA.com` and `domain.com`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
```

which means the following rule only applies to any request for `domainA.com` or `www.domainA.com`.

```
RewriteRule ^(referencepage)/?$ http://www.DomainM.com/$1 [P,NC]
```

This line  says change the request domain to  `www.DomainM.com` if user has asked for home page (`http://domainA.com/`)  or referencepage (`http://domainA.com/referencepage`).

But your rewrite rule has **P**  flag which means rewritten URL will be passed through proxy.

If both `DomainM.com`  and `domainA.com` are on the same server, I advise you to remove the **P** flag to avoid that (which means requests will take less time).

---

About your first question:
If you want to know what takes time to load you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/firebug/) (firefox) or IE's developer Tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

IE Developer Tools:
[image: IE Developer Tools]

FireBug:
[image: FireBug]

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I didn't realise Firebug did a loading readout - I've used that, this morning. I did rewrite my htaccess code (please see my question - update) . I tried to run the htaccess without the `[P]` tag but that changed the domain on the URL so that doesn't give me what I'd like to see. Thanks for the feedback and I hope you can advise further from my update!

Comment: As the Proxy flag seems to be required then the sites are not on the same server, but are under the same overall account on cPanel.

Comment: @Martin **P** flag passes the request through proxy, no matter if they're on the same server or not. It doesn't send **Location** header to user which is required  for external redirects(that's **R** flag's job). Can you put your whole htaccess here?

Comment: I have added the complete .htaccess as it stands at the moment, to the Update 2. cheers.

Comment: removing the P flag (or replacing the P flag with R flag) results in the displayed domain being changed. :-/

Comment: Ok, I checked, those domains are not on the same server (Not the same IPs) , so removing **P** flag will cause external redirect!

Comment: If it's possible, you can move them to same account and same server , it that case you can use internal redirect instead of using mod_proxy!

Comment: Well my client has several (6) domains, and wants the content from 1 to be displayed across the other 5 as well, so I really doubt we could get all 6 sites on the single server - (that would also then have very high traffic).

Comment: My original question was in two parts - Is my `htaccess` shape / code ok or can the htaccess be improved (I think you've answered tbh). And  I have found from other -exchange sites people mentioning that the Proxy flag is a security risk - if you agree can you explain (briefly) how so? Many thanks.

Comment: And researching the speed issue, I think the majority of the speed lag is actually the image sizes rather than the redirection. Cheers

Comment: Take a look at this page for security risks of using mod_proxy: [Link](http://statichtml.com/2011/mod_rewrite-proxy-caution.html). And One other thing that is not mentioned in that page is the fact you may have no control over what's being sent to your users.